# Redirect blogpage /blog/abcd/ to /blog/

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I want to redirect the url if it contains the string like `/blog/abcd.../` to blog listing page i.e. `/blog page`. I used a to code in htaccess file.

`Redirect 301 /blog/abcd http://www.example.com/blog`

But the browser says `Too many redirect` error. I think Wordpress also do a redirection for blog single post that is `/blog/abcd` to `/abcd`. Can we force htaccess to do redirect if url contains `/blog/` to blog listing page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it by the following code

```
RewriteRule  /blog/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/  http://www.example.com/blog  [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

A URL like `/blog/abcd.../` will redirect to the 404 page, you can redirect the 404 page to the blog page, [This](https://wordpress.org/plugins/404-redirection/) plugin will do what you want.